# How to test for null string in node xslt

Tags: xslt

Original source of xml

```
<SubdivisionType>
         <ID>null</ID>
         <Name>null</Name>
         <Parent i:nil="true"/>
</SubdivisionType>
```

String 'null' is generated by E4X. I have to check if SubdivisionType/ID contains another value then 'null' then skip all SubdivisionType tag.

Here is how i do

```
<xsl:if test="SubdivisionType/ID[text()!=null]" >
   ...
</xsl:if>
```

I can't understand how xlst(saxon) treats string 'null'.

Comment: Saxon or any other XSLT processor treats it like any other string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know saxon specifically, but as far as I'm aware, that isn't a "null string"... it's a string with the value "null".

I would try changing...

```
text()!=null
```

to...

```
text()!='null'
```

so that it reads...

```
<xsl:if test="SubdivisionType/ID[text()!='null']">
```

Answer (score 0):

@Simar,

if we conside below as the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<SubdivisionType>
<ID>null</ID>
<Name>null</Name>
<Parent nil="true"/>
</SubdivisionType>
<SubdivisionType>
<ID>asd</ID>
 <Name>null</Name>
<Parent nil="true"/>
</SubdivisionType>
</xml>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match = "SubdivisionType[ID = 'null']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<SubdivisionType>
<ID>asd</ID>
<Name>null</Name>
<Parent nil="true"/>
</SubdivisionType>
</xml>
```